# Remove folder name from URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

here is my URL like:

> example.com/abc/xyz/controller/function

here in above URL `abc` and `xyz` are folder name.

how to remove "abc" and "xyz" from URL using `.htaccess`?

here is my `.htaccess`:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]
> ```

Comment: Just confirming ... in your project where is the .htaccess that you modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the *abc* and *xyz* in *example.com/abc/xyz/controller/function* using `.htaccess` do this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?abc/xyz/controller/function/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /controller/function [NC,R,L]
```

---

The bottom two lines will remove the first two folders from links of the format *example.com/letters/letters/letters/letters* :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?[a-z]+/[a-z]+/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]
```

---

This accepts any characters for folder names and deletes the first two folders from the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Are the abc and xyz only example folders or do they really exist?

Comment: just for example, in my case i am using different name.

Comment: but yes its really exist with different name

Comment: Ok then replace the bottom two lines with the new bottom two lines from my edit.

Comment: do your folders contain only letters or do they have other characters like `-
 _ 0 1 2 3` etc.?

Comment: @jaypatel I edited, try the bottom answer as it will accept any characters for folder names (this is just to test that this works).

Comment: still not, and its only having alphabetical character

Comment: I edited question you can now have a look at my htaccess.

Comment: You have to use `Options +FollowSymLinks`. Instead of `RewriteEngine on` write the top three lines from my code (they also contain the line `RewriteEngine on`). Then move the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]` up above the `RewriteCond $1 !^(index ...` and try again please.

Comment: thanx for your great response @Ivan86, but the problem is still there its not worked

Comment: @jaypatel is this run on a local machine (e.g. WAMP, XAMP, LAMP) or on a web server?

Comment: this issue is now solved by some other stuff because htaccess was not work from any side.

Comment: @Ivan86 I used your code and its working fine for me but only when this is being used alone.                                                                                      `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @Ivan86 please see my answer below and please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folderName/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.


    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this will remove also index.php file or any other `/abc/xyz/` .That is just an example.